# How to make scrollock in Linux to work as it does in FreeBSD?

Tags: linux, command-line, gui, freebsd

In FreeBSD it's possible to scroll screen buffer back and forth after pressing [scrollock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_lock) how to make it work like this in Linux. I hope there is a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're talking about the actual textual terminal console; out of the box you can see history differently in FreeBSD and Linux: in FreeBSD you ScrollLock and then PageUp/PageDown, while in Linux (AFAIR) you Shift-PageUp/PageDn to the same effect.

If your question was "how to see the history in Linux" well, that's your answer: remember to use Shift+PageUp instead of ScrollLock+PageUp.

If, OTOH, what you really meant was "I know I can do that, but I would prefer to use the very same keypresses I'm accustomed with already" then I fear I can't help you, as I don't know Linux ttys so well myself. I wonder if that's even feasible with a simple configuration or if those keypresses are somewhat hardwired in the console software.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this depends on the terminal emulator you are using. The [article you linked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_lock) to, for instance, mentions that the KDE terminal, Konsole, offers the desired behavior.